# Format text in TextBox with thousand separated commas

Tags: c#, uwp

This is for an UWP app. It's a simple calculator. Whatever numbers the user types in, let's say you type in "1234", the TextBox needs to automatically put the comma in and make it "1,234". Tried the following but I think it's from asp.net so it's not working.

```
private void TextBoxEquation_TextChanging(
    TextBox sender, TextBoxTextChangingEventArgs args)
{
    textBoxEquation.Text = textBoxEquation.Text.ToString("n0");
}
```

Comment: You will need to format it in xaml, or format it when you originally add it. you cant format a string like that, only a numeric value. You could however, test for a numeric value using TryParse and format the result. however that will lead you down a very slippery slope

Comment: If it is only for presentation purpose ,it is better to do  using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `ToString("n0")` only works for int value, For your requirement, We suggest convert input value to int with thousand separated commas after finish input. Because it will posit the cursor wrong position when textBoxEquation.Text was set value.

```
var value = string.Format("{0:N0}", Int64.Parse(TestTB.Text));
TestTB.Text = value;
```

**Update**

If you want to keep four decimal precision Please use the following code. And Please note **We suggest convert input value to int with thousand separated commas after finish input**

```
var value = string.Format("{0:N4}", double.Parse(TestTB.Text,System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any));
TestTB.Text = value;
```

If you do not want convert the input value after finish to type. You could bind TextBlock `Text` property like the following and set `UpdateSourceTrigger` as `LostFocus`.

```
<TextBox x:Name="TestTB" Text="{x:Bind TestText,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"/>
```

**Code Behind**

```
private string _testText;
public string TestText
{
    get
    {

        return _testText;

    }
    set
    {

        _testText = string.Format("{0:N4}", double.Parse(value, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any));
         OnPropertyChanged("TestText");

    }

}
```

Comment: it only puts the first comma. for a long number it needs to be like this including decimals 1,234,567.5480

Answer (score 0):

Can try this solution:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var TB = sender as TextBox;
            string textValue = TB.Text.Replace(",", "");
            if (double.TryParse(textValue, out result))
            {
                TB.TextChanged -= TextBox_TextChanged;
                TB.Text = string.Format("{0:#,#}", result);
                TB.SelectionStart = TB.Text.Length;
                TB.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
            }
      }
```